# beautifulsoupでのスクレイピングの際のAttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

**実行環境**
windows10
python3
jupyterlab

**実現したいこと**
ツイキャスのランキングから、配信者の名前とツイキャスプロフィールのURL、そしてtwitterURLを
入手したいと考えています。

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://twitcasting.tv/rankingajax.php?d=20210803&type=daily&genre=&limit=100&cat=like'
res = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
#ツイキャスユーザーネーム取得
Unames = soup.find_all('strong') #name

data = []
for i in range(100):
    haisinsya = Unames[i].text #配信者名前
    caslinks = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class':'fullname smalldate'}) #ツイキャスすべてのリンク
    caslink = caslinks[i].text #タグを消し手最初の一つ
    linkend = caslink[1:] #@の削除
    #linkend
    casurl = 'https://twitcasting.tv/' + linkend #ツイキャスリンク前半と後半を合わせる
    #print(casurl)
    res2 = requests.get(casurl) #userlink
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(res2.text, 'html.parser')
    
    twilinktag = soup2.find(href=re.compile("http://twitter.com/"))
    twilink = twilinktag.get('href')
    
    #print(twilink)
    details = {}
    detum = details
    detum['配信者'] = haisinsya
    detum['ツイキャスURL'] = casurl
    detum['TwitterURL'] = twilink
    #print(twilink)
    data.append(detum)

print(data)    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)   
df.to_csv('ツイキャス.csv')
```

**エラーコード**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-b8946fd02a1e> in <module>
     25     #twilink = alllink[1].attrs['href'] #全てのリンクからTwitterリンクを指定
     26     twilinktag = soup2.find(href=re.compile("http://twitter.com/"))
---> 27     twilink = twilinktag.get('href')
     28 
     29     #print(twilink)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

**問題点**
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'　のエラーに戸惑っています。
解決策がわかりません。
わかる人教えてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

twilinktagがNoneの場合にこのエラーが出ているのだと思います。

```
    twilinktag = soup2.find(href=re.compile("http://twitter.com/"))
```

次のようにチェックをいれてはいかがでしょうか？

```
    twilinktag = soup2.find(href=re.compile("http://twitter.com/"))
    if twilinktag is None:
        continue
    twilink = twilinktag.get('href')
```

Comment: しっかり動作しました！ありがとうございます！

Comment: @zumo1224 うまくいって良かったです。よろしければ回答の承認をお願いします。承認していただければうれしいです。回答の左側にあるチェックマークをチェックすると承認ができます。